# Angular app looks different when deployed on Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

When I run the app locally it works fine but when I deploy it on [firebase](https://codeforces-helper.web.app/) it looks very different. I am using the @angular/material": "^9.2.4". Is there some problem with loading the material package?
[Here](https://github.com/salmaan25/cf-helper) is the link to the Github repository for the project if anyone wants to check it out.

For firebase deployment, I'm following [this](https://angular.io/start/start-deployment)

[image: when hosted on firebase]

[image: when hosted locally using ng serve]

Comment: yes. looks like material is not loaded here

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Do you know how I could load everything properly? I did not find any resources regarding this. I am new to angular and web development.

Comment: @Salmaan can you go through this page
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8577

Comment: Thanks. I will go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing index.html at line 11.

That line seems to be broken and/or invalid HTML.

I assume it will fail loading the CSS files and end up in unexpected behavior depending in what browser you are running. :-)

Maybe this fixes your issue with deployed firebase version.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `~` (tilde) in the import.
In the `style.css` change the import to

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

[Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#import):

> To import styles from a node_modules path (include resolve.modules)
> and for alias, prefix it with a ~:
>
> ```
> @import url(~module/style.css) => require('module/style.css')  
> @import url('~module/style.css') => require('module/style.css')  
> @import url(~aliasDirectory/style.css) =>
> require('otherDirectory/style.css')
> ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an issue. I made the changes but I'm still facing the same issue. Any further help would be appreciated.